# Need to make a list of the outstanding GPA’s from the array Im making (GPA’s over 3.4). Prefer traditional loop solution over some ES6 function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, if-statement

I need help with getting a list of GPAs over 3.4. I was able to sort largest to smallest, average, and get min and max GPAs utilizing traditional approaches (not ES6).

```
<div id ="out"></div>
<script>
var gpas = [];
var thegpas = " ";
var total = 0
while (thegpas != "XXX")
{
    thegpas = prompt("Enter gpas or XXX to Stop");
    if(thegpas != "XXX"){
        gpas.push(thegpas);
    } else  {
        break;
        
    }
    
}

for(var x = 0; x < gpas.length; x++)
{
    a = gpas.sort((a,b)=>b-a);
    total=total + parseFloat(gpas[x]);
    b = total/gpas.length //parseFloat(total)/length;
    var max = gpas[0];
    var min = gpas[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < gpas.length; ++i) {
        if (gpas[i]>max) {
            max = parseFloat(gpas[i]);
        }
        else if (gpas[i] < min) {
            min = parseFloat(gpas[i]);
            
        }
    }
    //need help with this part
    //outstandingGPAs=0;
   outstandingGPAs = [];
   cutoff = 3.4;
   if (gpas[x]>cutoff){
        outstandingGPAs.push(parseFloat(gpas[x])); 
    }

    out= "Largest to smallest " + a + "<br/>" + "GPAs average: " + b + "<br/>" + " Max and Min: " + max + ", " + min + "<br/>" + "Outstanding GPAs (greather than 3.4): " + outstandingGPAs ;
    
   // alert(gpas[x]);
}
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=out;
```

Current Output: [image: outputimage]

Comment: It's unclear what issue you run into. Is something not working or behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer loop?

Comment: There is no joy in not being allowed to use a language specification that has been published 5 years ago. What is your problem with ES6??

Answer (score 0):

Best way to output a (not very long) array is the **join** function.
In your output, you should use:

```
out = "<whatever you put>" + outstandingGPAs.join();
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=The%20join()%20method%20creates,returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator.) for more explanation of the **join** function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are *already* looping over your `gpas` array you could save those that are over 3.4 while you do that.
You would do that *within* your existing loop, not afterwards.

```
const cutoff = 3.4;
let outstandingGPAs = [];
// ...

for (var i = 1; i < gpas.length; ++i) {
    if (gpas[i]>max) {
        max = parseFloat(gpas[i]);
    }
    else if (gpas[i] < min) {
        min = parseFloat(gpas[i]);
    }

    // added to the existing loop
    if (gpas[i] > cutoff) {
        outstandingGPAs.push(gpas[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop should not be there, as you just redo the same operation over and over again.

As you only push at most one value in `outstandingGPAs` after you have set it to the empty array, that result will be wrong.

There are several other similar issues going on...

Also, getting input with `prompt` is really not user-friendly. The way to do this, is using an `input` element, and let the user type all values freely, and go back and correct whenever they want, and when they are happy with it, they can press a button so the code can run on it.

Here is how that looks:

```js
var calcButton = document.getElementById("calc");
var gpasInput = document.getElementById("gpas");
var outDiv = document.getElementById('out');

calcButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var min = Infinity,
        max = -Infinity,
        total = 0,
        gpas = [],
        outstandingGPAs = [];
    // Collect the input as an array of strings with number-related characters
    var inputStrings = gpasInput.value.match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);

    for (var i = 0; i < inputStrings.length; i++) {
        var num = parseFloat(inputStrings[i]);
        gpas.push(num);
        if (num > 3.4) {
            outstandingGPAs.push(num);
        }
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
        total += num;
    }
    var average = total / gpas.length;
    gpas.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    // lets also sort the outstanding GPAs
    outstandingGPAs.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    outDiv.innerHTML = "Largest to smallest " + gpas.join(", ") + "<br>" 
                     + "GPAs average: " + average + "<br>"
                     + "Max and Min: " + max + ", " + min + "<br>" 
                     + "Outstanding GPAs (greather than 3.4): " + outstandingGPAs.join(", ");
});
```

```html
Enter gpas values: <input id="gpas">
<button id="calc">Calculate</button><br>

<div id ="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```js
let theGpas = "";
let gpaArr = [];
while(theGpas != "XXX"){
theGpas = prompt("Enter GPAs. Enter XXX to stop.");
if(theGpas != "XXX"){
gpaArr.push(theGpas);
}
}
gpaArr = gpaArr.sort();
document.write("Largest to Smallest: "+gpaArr.join(",")+"<br/>");
function average(array){
var totalSum = 0;
for(var n in array){
totalSum += array[n];
}
return totalSum/array.length;
}
function moreThanArray(array, comparison){
var returnArr = [];
for(var z in array){
if(array[z]>comparison){
returnArr[returnArr.length] = array[z];
}
}
return returnArr;
}
const averageOf = average(gpaArr);
document.write("GPAs average: "+averageOf+"<br/>");
document.write("Max and Min: "+gpaArr[gpaArr.length-1]+", "+gpaArr[0]);
document.write("<br/>"+"Outstanding GPAs (greater than 3.4): "+moreThanArray(gpaArr, 3.4).join(","));
```